# After 2 un-up-votes, rep shows +5 too high in one place (originally ->(Notification of privileges to up vote and flag, but reputation too low!))

Tags: bug, status-completed

***Updated Bug/Question:***

See these two images:

e.se/rep...->[image]

and

view of 'accounts' on my profile page -- @ **meta**.e.se *only* --:

-->[image]

Edit:I guess I better add this image too, so you guys aren't clicking around more than needed:

[image]

(to confirm I'm not being silly, I supply these two images of my Avatar/Rep on both meta.e.se and e.se, you guys know which is which from background colors, like the image above):

[image] [image]

***Original Q Below:***

I only have 13 rep, but I have notifications that I have earned the privileges for:

1. Flagging
2. Up voting

Both require rep 15 minimum.
Indeed, I cannot use the privileges, I have tried to up vote, but still cannot.

[image]

Comment: You probably got up to or over 15, got a downvote or unupvote and ended up with 13. The notifications come almost as soon as it sees the right rep, even if it doesn't hold

Comment: Wouldn't I see that in my reputation log? Or in my notifications though too?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. However, note that your rep shows up as 18 if you check your associated accounts, so possibly there was an unupvote. You (and mods, I think) are the only ones who can see if that happened.

Comment: Lol.  I see what you mean but I think that's bc someone just up voted this question meta.  My rep is still 13 on english.se.

Comment: Rep on Meta is tied to your rep on the main site. And I meant that, if I click your user profile here on Meta, your associated ELU count showed 18 rep.

Comment: Right, meta adds to regular rep that acts as the 'base'. But the up vote on meta happened after I posted this question, and I still can't up vote on ELU proper.

Comment: No, you don't get rep from MEta

Comment: Where did that extra 5 come from in that listing? I maintain it wasn't there when I asked the question, and that it's not the same theoretical 5 that you originally suggested. I see however that some or all badges are separate for regular and meta sites? Thanks for helping me with this btw.  It's not of great concern, I just want help eliminate bugs here so things aren't confusing for new users.

Comment: Let me rephrase,  I didn't see the 18 count in that view until sometime after posting this question, fairly certain it showed up after my meta up vote.  Whether there is a connection idk.  Either way this still seems like a bug of incorrectly counted rep that only seems to appear when looking at my profile from meta.elu.  Should I change the bug report to cover this only/as well then?

Comment: Okay, so I re-read the info about voting and it would have shown if I got down voted I think so maybe someone unupvoted like you said.  But why then does it display this way?  Is this not a bug at least?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "bug." :^)  In this case, let's assume the unupvote theory is correct.  The system was right to have notified you when you got the privilege, and the system was right to not let you perform the function when your rep fell below the threshold. So the only odd thing is that the notifications didn't disappear, but I'm not so sure that's how the system should be designed. It'll be interesting to see if you get re-notified when you re-cross the threshold.

Comment: Indeed. I will report that here. For the time being, I am _still_ wondering about my Rep being listed as "18" when you click on my profile **from meta.english.stackexchange only** and scroll down to list all my accounts on SE. It doesn't appear anywhere else on any other site, on any other page, even at the top under my avatar _on that same page_, including english.SE. Is this not a bug that there is listed the rep from an up vote that was revoked? I know we're getting really specific here, and the topic has somewhat mutated...

Comment: If you visit http://english.stackexchange.com/reputation it will show you everything that has happened to your account, reputation-wise.

Comment: so basically, I got two 'un-upvotes' it would appear. (thanks for awesome link btw).

Comment: Comments Below here have been made after my Question was updated.

Comment: So all of the above images are current, until someone up-votes from one question on E.SE.

Comment: My one question on ELU got down voted and that caused the error in displayed Rep to be fixed (now both profile pages say 11). I still think what happened with rep number was a bug. Why should one up vote that was retracted be displayed on rep on meta.ELU only?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the reputation for site A shown on site B is different from the reputation shown on site A is explained on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114552/140449).

> Sathya is correct - this is due to caching elements of the page. Look again and you will find all of your reputation scores are now synced.

The answer then says:

> *Note*: it may still be up to **10 minutes** (cache duration) out of date for the *other* sites, since it's not really reasonable to keep it real-time across the entire network.

If the reputation is still wrong after more than 30 minutes, then see [My Meta SO rep showing wrong on my user profile on network sites except Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125399/my-meta-so-rep-showing-wrong-on-my-user-profile-on-network-sites-except-meta-so) which is still without an answer.

The message that notifies you about new privileges is shown once you reach the necessary reputation; if your reputation gets lower than the necessary reputation, you don't get a message saying you don't have anymore that privilege. Then, once a notification is added for you, there isn't a way to remove it if it doesn't apply anymore for you.

Comment: The problem is, this was _over_ **3** _days_ that this ("cache"?) lasted, not a mere 10 minutes. In fact it lasted _until_ I got an increase in my reputation on the 18th. I also learned that the notifications will **not** show again, with first hand experience, after you cross a rep threshold for the second time.

Comment: I read through the linked Question you just added. However, this _is not_ what was happening. An Un-upvote became permanent on meta.EL&U's meta.profile list of accounts, as is shown above in my images. The other question you linked to is regarding people have a meta score of **1**, when it should be much higher. Could be linked in the code somehow, I don't know, but it's a different manifestation due to different inputs even so.

Comment: The fact you have a reputation higher than 1 doesn't influence the bug, which is still the same: the reputation shown in an SE site for another SE site is not correct.

Comment: Please read my first comment to your answer. I don't think cache for a site this busy should last more than 72 hours, please explain with that in mind. It is not 30 minutes, it is not 10 minutes. it was, from what I can tell, until I received another change in my reputation, you can see this by looking at my reputation graph on e&lu proper. Therefore, I do not believe this is the bug you referenced.

Comment: See the second link you find on my answer. That question is for reputation that is not correctly shown for more than 10 minutes.

Comment: So are you saying the questions should be merged? If so I would recommend that the two different 'inputs' for the bug to happen be kept as record, since they were a little bit different. Thanks kiamlaluno, your meaning got confused in my mind somehow.

Comment: Also, see the update in the first link.  I'm going to mark this is status completed because: a) it looks fixed, and b) things have changed enough from 2012 that this is going to be pretty hard to run down.  If it keeps occurring file a new bug.